# I just added Firebase to my Unity Project and am now getting a Gradle Build Failed Error

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I just added Firebase to my Unity project. When trying to build the project to my android tablet I am getting a Gradle Build Failed error.
I have tried multiple devices, but am not sure what the issue is. I have provided the error below:

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 81233 > 65536)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Including libraries, your project has surpassed 64k methods, you need to enable multidex for your project. Look at this: [Dealing with the 64K Method Limit in Your Unity3D Game](https://blog.kongregate.com/dealing-with-the-64k-method-limit-in-your-unity3d-game/)